# how to pass a callback in typescript to a function?

Tags: typescript

I'm getting an error:

`src/index.ts:9:18: ERROR: Expected identifier but found "function"`

```
export default {
    chargeCreditCard(function(): Function {
        console.log('chargeCreditCard call complete.');
    });
};
```

and:

```
export const chargeCreditCard = (cb: Function) => {
    const authType = authorizeNet();
    const creditCard = new ApiContracts.CreditCardType();
    creditCard.setCardNumber('4242424242424242');
    creditCard.setExpirationDate('0822');
    creditCard.setCardCode('999');

...
}
```

How do I fix this?

Getting error passing a function as argument to another function in typescript.

Comment: chargeCreditCard(()=>{console.log('chargeCreditCard call complete.')})

Comment: ` src/index.ts:9:18: ERROR: Expected identifier but found "("`

Comment: The code looks very strange to me: so where are you exporting the `chargeCreditCard` function and where are you consuming it? Both snippets indicate that you have the intention to export the function.

Comment: in the same file.

Comment: You have two functions named the same, if they are in the same file, TS will complain, whether you pass one with a callback or not

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: No i don't. the first block calls the function `chargeCredit(cb)`

Comment: I'm trying to call `chargeCreitCard` with a callback as an argument. Simple as that.

Comment: I have the feeling that your "export default" play against you. What are you trying to export as a default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite not being very clear what you are doing, answering your core question,  this is how you pass a callback function to another function's parameter.

```
const chargeCreditCard = (callback: Function) => {
  console.log('chargeCreditCard() function called!');
  callback();
}
```

If you want to call this function do something like

```
chargeCreditCard(() => console.log('parameter'))
```

Comment: I have that, but how do I call it? That's where the error is.

Comment: I have added a simple example on how to call it

Answer (score 0):

here I notice that you are passing callback function in wrong way this is the cause of error because you are defining the function in parameter.

I think you have to define callback function with its body and the pass it to the function in which you want to call the callback function or use the fat arrow function.

```
//define callback
function() callbackfunction {
        console.log('chargeCreditCard call complete.');
    }
```

```
//pass as parameter
        chargeCreditCard(callbackfunction);
```

```
// call it like
export const chargeCreditCard = (cb: Function) => {
    const authType = authorizeNet();
    const creditCard = new ApiContracts.CreditCardType();
    creditCard.setCardNumber('4242424242424242');
    creditCard.setExpirationDate('0822');
    creditCard.setCardCode('999');

//calling callback
   cb();

...
}
```

so, it should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

It's not completely clear what are you trying to achieve but the

```
export default {
    chargeCreditCard(function(): Function {
        console.log('chargeCreditCard call complete.');
    });
};
```

Is not a valid syntax, you should replace it with

```
export default {
    chargeCreditCard() {
        console.log('chargeCreditCard call complete.');
    }
};
```

Comment: `chargeCreditCard` is another function. This doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: It is still not clear what are you doing, in the first piece of code you are exporting an object with a method named `chargeCreditCard` using an invalid syntax.

Comment: In the second example, you are exporting a constant named `chargeCreditCard`